# Can we provide a processor before onFallbackViaNetwork() in camel-hystrix-eip

Tags: apache-camel, hystrix

I'm using camel-hystrix-eip in my project, I want a processor before my fallback, but it's not working

```
from("direct:sample").id("id:direct:sample").process(requestProcessor)
                .hystrix()
                .to(endPoint)
                .onFallbackViaNetwork()
                .to(fallback_endPoint)
```

I want to alter my fallback_endpoint using a processor, but seems like after on`FallbackViaNetwork()` we have to immediately provide `to()`.
please suggest if there any way to do so.

I tried something like below, but it's not working.

```
from("direct:sample").id("id:direct:sample").process(requestProcessor)
                .hystrix()
                .to(endPoint)
                .onFallbackViaNetwork()
                .process(fallbackProcessor)
                .to(fallback_endPoint)
```

Actually, I'm using requestProcessor to override the actual endpoint, and in case of a fallback, `fallback_endPoint` is also getting overridden, is there any way to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a processor after `onFallbackViaNetwork()`. You can also use the `toD` EIP to send the message to a dynamic endpoint.

Based on your code, you could set a Header `MyEndpoint` which contains your new endpoint string, and then reference it using `.toD("${header.MyEndpoint}")`. Repeat this pattern whenever you need to set a dynamic endpoint.

For example:

```
from("direct:sample")
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            // do something
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("EndpointHystrix", "mock:hystrix");
        }
    })
    .hystrix()
        .toD("${header.EndpointHystrix}")
    .onFallbackViaNetwork()
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                // do something more
                exchange.getIn().setHeader("EndpointFallback", "mock:fallback");
            }
        })
        .toD("${header.EndpointFallback}")
    .end()
    .to("...");
```

I've tested this in Camel 2.20.0 and 2.21.0.